# Problems upgrading Ipython (prompt_toolkit incompatibilities)

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

Trying to open a jupyter notebook file (.ipynb file) 
with this command `ipython notebook filename.ipynb` then I am getting Below Error while using ipython..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Python\Scripts\ipython.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
from .terminal.embed import embed
File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 16, in 
<module>
from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\interactiveshell.py", 
line 18, in <module>
from prompt_toolkit.enums import DEFAULT_BUFFER, EditingMode
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompt_toolkit'
```

Comment: try install prompt toolkit `pip install prompt_toolkit`

Comment: Done and i got this message but the issue is not resolved -> Requirement already satisfied: prompt_toolkit in /home/chirag/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.0.15)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /home/chirag/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from prompt_toolkit) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /home/chirag/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from prompt_toolkit) (1.11.0)

Comment: This is a valid `ipython` error report.  Others of us have encountered this.  It should be reopened.  But it's probably better reported as a ipython/jupyter bug.

Comment: A relevant bug issue: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/370.  There appears to be a conflict in dependencies in different parts of the jupyter install.  We may have to wait a day or two for it to be straightened out.

Comment: For now I've got a cleaner install using `ipython==6.5` rather than the latest.

Comment: And https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11341

Answer (score 43):

Just got the same problem.

The solution for me was to `pip uninstall prompt-toolkit` and `pip install prompt-toolkit`. This uninstalled v1.0.5 and installed v2.0.4.

Comment: It works for me. Thank you. I did `pipenv install prompt-toolkit==2.0.4`.

Comment: I just encountered this problem as well when upgrading `jupyter`.  Uninstalling the `prompt-toolkit`, and doing a clean install seemed to do the trick.  But secondary indents aren't behaving quite right.

Comment: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11337 is the issue that I encountered with v7.  I could only create one line function definitions.

Comment: Instead of uninstalling and removing, you can also just upgrade the package with `pip install --upgrade prompt-toolkit`