# How to solve the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompt_toolkit.formatted_text' in Jupyter Notebook inside the Pycharm IDE?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I am using Pycharm 2018.2 version in ubuntu 18.04 and I am trying to use the *JupyterNoteBook* inside the pycharm it's been loading and creating a new notebook. But the cell in the Jupyter always shows busy and it throws some error like *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompt_toolkit.formatted_text'*. Eventhough, I restarted the kernel again and again it throws the same error. Even I uninstalled and after the re-installation it throws the same error.
[Error it throws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MyEm.png)

Can aynone please help me to resolve this error?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There's some sort of bug in the latest `Jupyter` installation - apparently a conflict in the required version of `prompt_toolkit`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551878/problems-upgrading-ipython-prompt-toolkit-incompatibilities.  It's not you!

Comment: Thank you sir ! Is there any other way to use Jupyter in pycharm2018.2

Comment: The problem is solved by uninstalling the old prompt_toolkit version and upgrading it to prompt_toolkit version 2.0.5 it works fine. It works for me thank you sir

Comment: @BhavaniKasiviswanathan, I am having the same problem. How did you go about uninstalling and upgrading? Can you post an answer to your own question too? That would help me and others. Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just upgrade the console:

```
pip install -U jupyter_console
```

Answer (score 4):

The link to the post from hpaulj in the first comment above provides the steps necessary to correct this issue. I, like Bhavani, followed the steps in that post, and my Jupyter notebook is now working. [HERE IS THE LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551878/problems-upgrading-ipython-prompt-toolkit-incompatibilities) for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the toolkit

1. pip uninstall prompt-toolkit
2. pip install --upgrade prompt-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

conda install -c conda-forge notebook