# Error in displaying Iris Dataset in Python

Tags: python, data-science

I am taking the data science course from Udemy. After running the code to show the iris data set, it does not show. Instead, it downloads a data file.

I am running the following code:

```py
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('<iframe src=http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data></iframe>')
```

Is the code correct? Could you please help how to show the iris dataset in the python using iframe?

link to the course: https://www.udemy.com/course/introduction-to-data-science-using-python/learn/lecture/9387344#questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ali, we can't embed just anything into iframes.

You could just read and display the file as

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data')

data
```

This would work just as fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip uninstall prompt-toolkit
pip install prompt-toolkit
```

The old version: 1.0.14

the new version: 3.0.2

repeated:
[Problems upgrading Ipython (prompt_toolkit incompatibilities)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551878/problems-upgrading-ipython-prompt-toolkit-incompatibilities)